# Propensity score matching for "large" datasets - smarter solution than nearest neighbour?

Tags: r, matching, propensity-scores

The following question has some programming / software package as well as some numerical aspects, but I would consider it a statistical question at heart - I hope you agree.

I am trying to do 1:1 propensity score matching in R for a dataset of about 4,000 treated and 16,000 untreated individuals. To do this, some "greedy" and some "optimal" methods seem to be available. The greedy methods, such as nearest neighbour (e.g. MatchIt package), seem to produce massively suboptimal results, while the "optimal" methods (e.g. MatchIt or optmatch) seem to crash for these sample sizes.

I suspect the greedy methods could be improved by adding an optimisation step after arriving at the initial solution, such as nearest neighbour followed by simulated annealing or similar to try to improve the pairing. However, no one seems to be doing that.

Are you aware of any solutions that can handle these sample sizes and produce a better solution than nearest neighbour? Is there any reason better methods are not available in current software?